# Auto.arima only returns NAs for fitted values if time series contains NAs and biasadj = TRUE

Tags: r, forecasting, hierarchical-data, arima

I am using the following forecasting code:

```
library(forecast)   
ts <- ts(c(AirPassengers, NA), frequency = frequency(AirPassengers), start = time(AirPassengers)[1])   
fit <- auto.arima(ts, lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE)
```

If the timeseries contains NAs the fitted values are just NAs.
If not, everything works fine.
This only occurs when biasadj = TRUE is used.
I really need this parameter, because the forecasts will be reconciliated afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug which is now fixed on github (https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/commit/ec10b4d671f2aba9f4f5b44d19a7f3c959f5511f). It occured because bias adjustment requires the variance of the residuals, and since the residuals contain NAs, the variance was set to NA. The NAs are now removed before the variance is computed.

You can install the github version of forecast using `devtools::install_github("robjhyndman/forecast")`.

```r
library(forecast)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo
ts <- ts(c(AirPassengers, NA), frequency = frequency(AirPassengers), start = time(AirPassengers)[1])   
fit <- auto.arima(ts, lambda = 0, biasadj = TRUE)
fitted(fit)
#>           Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug
#> 1949 111.7644 117.9244 131.9603 128.9940 121.0177 135.0168 148.0163 148.0257
#> 1950 117.0192 122.1417 139.4036 136.8668 127.1664 141.6609 160.9362 166.3608
#> 1951 135.0152 152.0046 169.1444 168.1832 154.4083 190.2018 205.1139 201.5096
#> 1952 169.5327 180.1300 207.1550 186.9879 181.4463 200.4014 235.9657 232.5887
#> 1953 199.3282 208.1657 223.9254 217.2754 227.5214 260.2296 272.3481 273.6836
#> 1954 207.9965 211.8017 227.6274 223.8273 223.0809 253.4382 282.7735 302.0030
#> 1955 232.6668 233.6070 278.9402 262.3460 268.2018 300.2183 343.9312 356.3116
#> 1956 284.1752 276.3670 324.8120 315.0016 315.6151 360.7117 417.2304 406.3885
#> 1957 316.9689 307.6216 352.4723 349.4975 352.2430 408.6635 466.4857 456.4817
#> 1958 351.1747 332.7414 379.1105 362.2221 358.9109 422.7420 478.1954 481.4878
#> 1959 349.9776 339.0096 394.1057 390.3720 404.5410 489.2669 536.1201 547.3600
#> 1960 419.0486 397.5631 460.5898 424.0306 464.5782 542.3447 612.1384 626.2449
#> 1961       NA                                                               
#>           Sep      Oct      Nov      Dec
#> 1949 136.0412 119.0550 104.0629 118.3815
#> 1950 155.1446 136.6225 117.2537 132.1821
#> 1951 185.0585 158.0349 138.8752 169.7223
#> 1952 220.1838 185.3222 166.5017 197.4332
#> 1953 244.5126 213.2651 188.7034 210.4479
#> 1954 262.6187 231.6730 201.0383 229.2421
#> 1955 310.3633 276.2481 241.7870 270.3036
#> 1956 361.4957 315.8971 270.6371 311.4373
#> 1957 409.4854 355.0057 307.7594 349.2082
#> 1958 434.0926 360.6985 316.1704 351.0444
#> 1959 466.5646 407.2515 355.0986 397.7856
#> 1960 513.2724 447.8723 400.9856 438.7865
#> 1961
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>